# how to prevent Quoted Orders from appear under both Quoted and Completed sections for the Orders page; Completed Orders also appear under both

Tags: views, commerce, 10

Orders are showing up in both COMPLETED and QUOTED..

my screenshot here shows only Quoted Order, yet they appear for BOTH:
[image: screenshot from CMS admin Order page showing Quoted and Completed orders.]

(please note the first screenshot does not feature any fully completed orders, but does exact same thing by appear in both sections)

This screenshot shows the filter options for each (which I suspect is what needs changing, but might be wrong) with Quoted on left and Completed on the right:
[image: screenshot from CMS admin showing options for Order fields and filters]

Do I just need to update the filters on the Commerce Orders Dashboard? or should I be looking elsewhere?

ALSO, for the Completed tab I tried to change `Order: State (= Quoted)` to `Order: State (= Paid)`

[image: screenshot of options set to Order: State (= Paid)]

...I though I would see the option 'Completed' but there is none:
[image: screenshot of popup to change drupal option of order state]

and that made a bit of a difference, but still not as expected because now both Quoted and Completed appear under the QUOTED section
[image: screenshot from CMS admin Order page showing Quoted and Completed orders, but all orders show under Quoted for some reason.]

Comment: Nothing in your filters list would actually filter out orders from the second based on type. Why not just add a filter to not show "Quote" type orders?

Comment: Filter criteria is the way to go. Your "quoted" view shows quoted because you put that Order: State (=Quoted). Your "completement" view shows orders regardless of their state because the filter criteria is missing (for example a Order: State (=Completed)

Comment: Hey guys, my bad, I posted screenshot from my adjusted local.. I updated it now with pic from staging. I sort of see what you mean... for completed tab I also see Order: State (= Quoted), but when I click on it to select another option, there is no completed, but I do see Paid as a choice, so will try Order: State (= Paid)

Comment: that did not seem to work :( ...I updated my Q

Answer (score 0):

Adding a couple new filters did the trick for me!

Go to the Commerce Orders Dashboard (Order) page:

`Home > Administration > Structure > Views > Commerce orders dashboard > Edit`

Choose the **Quoted** tab under the **Displays** label:

[image: Screenshot of tabs, Page, Hold, Pending, Billed, Invoiced, Quoted, Completed. The Quoted tab is highlighted.]

Then scroll down to **Filter criteria** label and choose the **Add** button:

[image: Screenshot of Add button to the right of the Filter criteria label]

A dialog modal window will popup to be able to **Add filter criteria**. Use the **Search* field to easily find the `Order type` option, then checkmark the **Order type** and click the **Apply (this display)** button:

[image: Screenshot of Add filter criteria modal showing the Order Type selected as it was filtered using the search field.]

..in the next dialog, just select `Quoted` under **Order types** and then click the **Apply (this display)** button:

[image: Screenshot of next modal view with cursor selecting Quote label under the Order types.]

Lastly, remember to save your change with the blue Save button (at the bottom) because you will notice at the top the asterisk* symbol after the **Quoted*** tab text, and above that you get the message "*You have unsaved changes.*"

[image: Screenshot showing Quoted with asterisk symbol and message You have unsaved changes.]

AFTERWARDS, for repeat the same steps but under the **Completed** tab:

[image: Screenshot of tabs, Page, Hold, Pending, Billed, Invoiced, Quoted, Completed. The Completed tab is highlighted.]

...and when you are filtering for the **Order types** for Completed you will want to select the `Order` checkbox, and the rest would be the same steps:

[image: Screenshot of last modal view with cursor selecting Order label under the Order types.]

After all that, the quoted orders appeared **only** under the QUOTED section, and the completed orders appeared **only** under the COMPLETED section!